# How to request MYSQL elements instead of using Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I made language php code which working fine. I request the translations from different like en.php, de.php.
In en.php i have one array:

```
$language = Array('homepage' => 'Site Home','contact' => 'Contact Us');
```

I use $_SESSION for get the language en, de, hu and the others. I get the language files with this code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM languages ORDER BY langID");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($count) {
    while ($ds = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        switch ($_SESSION['language']) {
            case $ds['tag']:
                include_once('language/' . $ds['tag'] . '.php');
                break;
            default:
                include_once('language/en.php');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like to change array for mysql database. In my DB i have a table with:

- translatesID
- tag(its now the 'en' or can be other like 'de')
- key(what i want to be the array like 'homepage')
- value(which would be the 'Site Home')

In index.php I get the 'Site Home' with the following php code:

```
<?php echo $language['homepage']; ?>
```

My question is which Mysql request or PHP code can solve my request?

Comment: http://php.net/pdo  since you've provided absolutely NOTHING in the way of useful details, e.g. database structures, actual query requirements, then "use pdo" is about the only useful answer you're going to get.

Comment: Its simple i would like to change array to MySQL datebase request. How can i get this <?php echo $language['homepage']; ?> if i have 'homepage' in my MySQL table under the 'key'element.

Comment: Which array do You wish to replace with MySQL result? The `$language`?

Comment: FYI: translations are best handled by tools made for handling translations, e.g.: gettext. You should only use a database if you're going to be adding new translations dynamically for some reason, like users adding them.

Comment: deceze yes that would be my aim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with this code:

```
$language = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM translates WHERE '" . $_SESSION['language'] . "' = tag");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $language[$row['key']] = $row['value'];
}
```